# How to make the output in tabular form

Tags: c++, formatting, tabular

Who could help me, can't figure out how to make my output for Charge-column. I need to make that output right under that charge column, but every time when I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> it makes a new line hence my output appears in new line. Also there is a zero after each output, don't know where is that come from. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
float calculateCharges(double x);
int main()
{
    int ranQty; //calculates randomly the quantity of the cars
    double pTime; // parking time
    srand(time(NULL));

    ranQty = 1 + rand() % 5;

    cout << "Car\tHours\tCharge" << endl;

    for(int i = 1; i <= ranQty; i++)
    {
    cout << i << "\t";
    cin >> pTime ;
    cout << "\t" << calculateCharges(pTime) << endl; 

    }
    return 0;  
}
float calculateCharges(double x)
{
    if(x <= 3.0) //less or equals 3h. charge for 2$
    {
        cout << 2 << "$";
    }
    else if(x > 3.0) // bill 50c. for each overtime hour 
    {
        cout << 2 + ((x - 3) * .5) << "$";
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding that extra zero, strange things happen when a function promises to return a value, but doesn't. `calculateCharges` is supposed to return a `float`, but maybe it shouldn't since it prints the results out for you.

Comment: As for your problem, I don't have a good solution. iostreams are too simple to do what you want. But if you read in all of the input, store it in a vector,and then compute and print you can get close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key each time to send your `pTime` from the command line to your program's standard input. This causes a new line. The new line is what causes the console to hand your input over to the program in the first place.

In order to print properly, you can simply store the `pTime` to an array(i.e, preferably in `std::vector`, as @user4581301 mentioned); calculate the required and print it.
something like:

```
#include <vector>

ranQty = 1 + rand() % 5;
std::cout << "Enter " << ranQty << " parking time(s)\n";
std::vector<double> vec(ranQty);
for(double& element: vec) std::cin >> element;

std::cout << "Car\tHours\tCharge" << std::endl;
for(int index = 0; index < ranQty; ++index)
   std::cout << index + 1 << "\t" << vec[index] << "\t" << calculateCharges(vec[index]) << "$" << std::endl;
```

> there is a zero after each output, don't know where is that come from.

`float calculateCharges(double x);` this function should return a `float` and your definition is something like a void function. Solution is:

```
float calculateCharges(double x)
{
   if(x <= 3.0)    return 2.0f;       // --------------> return float
   return 2.0f + ((x - 3.0f) * .5f) ; // --------------> return float
}
```